# Excel window:1 gone missing

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using Excel 2002, on an XP box, with 2GB of RAM.

I have a spreadsheet I've used repeatedly, which has always been saved with 2 windows.

All of a sudden window:1 disappeared, and now I only have window:2.
When I try to open another window in the workbook, it adds window:3, window:4, etc., 
but will never add window:1 again.  I've shutdown Excel, and also rebooted but nothing
remedies the issue.

Any idea of what's come undone, or how I can get window:1 back ?
Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Why does it matter what id each window is given?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like your `Window:1` has been hidden.  Check under the `Window` menu, if `Unhide...` is available.